# How to update Android contact company?

Tags: android, contacts, synchronization, contactscontract, android-contacts

I recently created a Sync adapter for my app,  It will sync contacts I am getting via a web request with the contacts in the phone.  I have no problem adding the contact, however I cannot get the contact information to correctly update when contact information has changed.  For example the Company Name field on the contact.  Here is some example queries I have tried that did not work or only partially worked(ie - some contacts updated but not correctly):

```
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.COMPANY, "New Company");
context.getContentResolver().update(Uri.parse("content://com.android.contacts/data/"), values, BaseColumns._ID + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(id) } );
```

I have also tried doing this in batch as suggested by the android documentation:

```
    builder = ContentProviderOperation
            .newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
    builder.withSelection(BaseColumns._ID + " =?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});

    builder.withValue(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.COMPANY,
            "New Company Name!");
    operationList.add(builder.build());
```

I have read the [ContactContracts Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html) and originally was following this [tutorial](http://www.c99.org/2010/01/23/writing-an-android-sync-provider-part-2/).  I also checked into the `AuthenticatorActivity` example in the api's to no avail.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After spending an exhausting amount of time trying to figure out the correct query, I believe I have found the answer.  It looks like i needed to change the `BaseColumns._ID` to `ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID` and for each update I made, I also had to supply the mime-type also I did not see this anywhere in the android documentation.  Much help was found on this write-up:  [Working With Android Contacts](http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Android-Contacts/)

```
        String orgWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?"; 
    String[] orgWhereParams = new String[]{String.valueOf(id), 
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE}; 
    operationList
    .add(ContentProviderOperation
            .newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withSelection(orgWhere, orgWhereParams)
            .withValue(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.DATA,
                    guCon.getCompany()).build());
```